# How to fetch an API in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, dynamic, axios

**Please suggest a way to fetch an API rather than importing JSON file from DATA folder.**

I am trying to fetch some data (API) as options in my
Filtered  multi-select component. Very new to react please suggest.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
   import FilteredMultiSelect from 'react-filtered-multiselect';
   import axios from 'axios';

class SlideOne extends Component  {
     
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
          selectedOptions: [],
        }
      }
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/xcfy7/")
         .then((response)=>{
          this.setState(()=>{
                   return {
                     selectedOptions: response.data.tax
                   }
          })
         })     
    }
     
    handleDeselect = (deselectedOptions) => {
        var selectedOptions = this.state.selectedOptions.slice()
        deselectedOptions.forEach(option => {
          selectedOptions.splice(selectedOptions.indexOf(option), 1)
        })
        this.setState({selectedOptions})
    }
    
    handleSelect = (selectedOptions) => {
    
        selectedOptions.sort((a, b) => a.taxId - b.taxId)
        this.setState({selectedOptions})
    }
      
    render() {
        
     
      return (
    
          <div className="row">   
           <div className="col-md-6">
            <FilteredMultiSelect
              placeholder="Select from here"
              buttonText="Add"
              classNames={{
                filter: 'form-control',            
                select: 'form-control',
                button: 'btn btn btn-block btn-default',           
                buttonActive: 'btn btn btn-block btn-primary'
              }}
              onChange={this.handleSelect}
              options={this.state.selectedOptions}
              selectedOptions={this.state.selectedOptions}
              textProp="taxName"
              valueProp="taxId"
            />
          </div>      
          <div className="col-md-6">
             <FilteredMultiSelect
              placeholder="get selected here"
              buttonText="delete"
              classNames={{
    
                filter: 'form-control',            
                select: 'form-control',            
                button: 'btn btn btn-block btn-default',            
                buttonActive: 'btn btn btn-block btn-danger'
              
              }}
    
              onChange={this.handleDeselect}
              options={this.state.selectedOptions}
              textProp="taxName"
              valueProp="taxId"
            />
    
           
          </div>
        </div>)
        
    }}
   
    export default SlideOne;`
```

Comment: Please, format the code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to invoke remote APIs and fetch data. Make sure you include the data fetching in the [componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle event and invoke `setState()` with the fetched data to update the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I included data in componentDidMount() but unable to setState() while fetching the data. can you please explain for the above code

Comment: @Dheeraj can you provide the code in your componentDidMount() method?

Comment: edited the code.. please suggest a way to display all the options in my FilteredMultiselect component (form that remove api). very new to this still learning

Comment: accessing taxName as response.data.tax.taxName is invalid since tax is an array of objects.